# Flash Builder do not find classes for database connection

Tags: database, actionscript-3, flash

I'm doing a flash game in actionscript 3 using Flash Builder. I'd need to connect to a database. I found any kind of exaple to do that, but Flash Builder cannot find the path

> flash.data.SQLConnection,
>   flash.data.SQLMode, flash.events.SQLErrorEvent, flash.events.SQLEvent, and flash.filesystem.file.

Does anyone know the reason? I've look for this classes on the Net, but I hadn't success...

Comment: Are you running an Adobe AIR app? The `flash.data` and `File` class is only available to AIR apps. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/package-detail.html

Answer (score 0):

add this source path to your flash builder project :

\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\ [air sdk folder (4.6)] \frameworks\libs\air